# extraction not allowed page extraction pdf using python

Tags: python, security, pdf, extract

I'm using python to extract pdfs but the resent pdf gives me unacceptable result like this:
[image: unacceptable extraction result]

After searching I found that the pdf not allowed to extract:
[image: pdf security properties]

I tried to print as pdf, but still the same "page extraction: Not allowed", my question is what should I do to extract text in this pdf, there is no password and I can read and print any module in python or other language can do this?

Comment: Congratulations on your first post.  I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not the place to ask questions about how to overcome the security features of a software program.

Comment: thanks, i think it is not a security issue cause the pdf is able to extraction with unknown output i managed to get that every (cid:"number") represent a letter ex :(cid:68) represent a and (cid:36) represent A, (cid:70) represent b and (cid:37) represent B,
but i really don't know what is the algorithm or why this happen from the begging!, if you suggest any where i could search tell me

Comment: **(A)** The issue is unrelated to the restrictions you found. The summary you show refers not only to restrictions imposed by the document but also by the viewer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65021738/1729265) for details. You apparently looked at the summary using Acrobat Reader. If you had used Acrobat Pro, you'd have seen an "Allowed" there.

Comment: **(B)** The actual problem most likely is that your PDF simply does not contain the information required for text extraction; i.e. it uses character identifiers (cids) which point to drawing instructions for the glyph in a font program, so viewers know how to draw the glyph in question, but it does not indicate how to map from these character ids to Unicode code points.

Comment: thanks it was helpful to know this, i think i will map these cids to actual character do you suggest any thing else rather than mapping?