# Document Assembly is not changed when creating pdf by itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating a pdf and my project requirement is to manipulate the document security settings programmatically.

I am using itextSharp ver 1.7 and using c# as a programming language, below is the code snippet.

```
private static byte[] UpdateDocumentSecuritySettings(byte[] bytes, DocumentSecurity setting)
{
    byte[] userPassword = string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting.UserPassword) ? null : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(setting.UserPassword);
    byte[] ownerPassword = string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting.OwnerPassword) ? null : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(setting.OwnerPassword);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
        stamper.SetEncryption(
                userPassword, ownerPassword,
                    (setting.AllowScreenReader ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowDegradedPrinting ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowPrinting ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowCopy ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowModifyContent ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowModifyAnnotation ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowAssembly ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY : 0) |
                    (setting.AllowFillIn ? PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN : 0),
                PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS);
        stamper.Close();
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Irrespective of whatever I am passing on (true/false) it always shows Document Assembly: Not Allowed in Adobe pdf reader.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65021738/1729265), isn't it? In a nutshell: Adobe Reader never allows document assembly; it is a cut-down Acrobat version, so it simply does not offer certain functionality, no matter what the document creator allows.

Comment: That being said, a version 1.7 of itextsharp sounds weird.